# How can I put collection select within form_tag correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a model called **Genre**

There are already many records stored in that.
I tried to fetch all of the records from Genres table, and show them all in select. 
See below what I coded in my view.
But this returns error like this. How can I solve this?

> undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol

**my view**

```
  <%= form_tag communities_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
   <div class="input-append">
    <%= form.collection_select :id, Genre.all, :id, :name %>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I can't see where the form variable is being set? If it isn't then remove it and use an identifier for it `collection_select :genre, :id, Genre.all, :id, :name`

Comment: Aha, now it works Thanks so much. Could you please make an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`collection_select` requires an identifier as the first argument and in the provided example the variable `form` is not set. Therefore the code should read:

```
<%= form_tag communities_path, :method => :get, :class => 'form-search' do %>
 <div class="input-append">
  <%= collection_select :genre, :id, Genre.all, :id, :name %>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
 </div>
<% end %>
```